# 3rd Party framework: Xcode keeps looking in /Library/Frameworks/

Tags: xcode

I'm stuck with including a 3rd party framework (written in Objective-C) into my Swift application. I did the following (which should be sufficient):

- Include the framework into the project
- Add the framework to the "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase
- Add the framework to the "Copy Files" build phase (destination: "Frameworks")
- Import the main header of the framework into the bridging header

Compiling the project succeeds. But as soon as I try to run it I receive the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/ZipKit.framework/Versions/A/ZipKit
```

Additionally I set the following settings:

- Runpath Search Paths: @executable_path/../Frameworks
- Framework Search Paths: @executable_path/../Frameworks (in addition to the source location of the framework)
- Library Search Paths: @executable_path/../Frameworks

Nothing seems to work and I don't have any clue why the runtime keeps looking in the /Library folder.

I'm currently using Xcode 6 Beta 6 (as the GM does not support Swift on OS X).

**Edit**
Just to clarify: The app bundle contains the linked framework after compilation (I've checked that).

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

Fortunately I have the source code of the framework I want to include.
I stumbled upon the `install path` setting of the framework project which was set to `/Library/Frameworks`.

I changed this to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` re-compiled it, re-compiled my project and now it works.

Comment: Just for posterity, you can also use install_name_tool on the command line to change the install path on a compiled framework, without having to recompile it.